# Add "Enter" and "Escape" key presses to Powershell WPF form

Tags: wpf, powershell

I used ISE-Sterioids template to create a simple 3 field WPF form that asks for three things:
- ID
- Email
- Reference
I have it sucessfully working with these fields when using the OK and Cancel buttons, but I would like to capter "Enter" to submit the form and "Escape" to cancel the form, but I am having difficulty adding the events.

I have tried similar code to the technet article here; but as this isn't using WPF I think I am missing something

```
$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter")
{$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
```

My code here:

```
#region XAML window definition
# Right-click XAML and choose WPF/Edit... to edit WPF Design
# in your favorite WPF editing tool

# Default Form Values
$123 = 'ID'
$toEmail = 'email address'
$ref = "ref"

$xaml = @'
<Window
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
   MinWidth="200"
   Width ="400"
   SizeToContent="Height"
   Title="Proofing script"
   Topmost="True">
    <Grid Margin="10,2,10,10">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5">Please enter your details:</TextBlock> -->

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5"><Run Text="Number:"/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5"><Run Text="To Email :"/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5"><Run Text="Salesforce Ref:"/></TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtName" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtEmail" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="ref" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5"/>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button x:Name="ButOk" MinWidth="80" Height="22" Margin="5" Content="OK" />
            <Button x:Name="ButCancel" MinWidth="80" Height="22" Margin="5" Content="Cancel" IsCancel="True" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
'@
#endregion

#region Code Behind
function Convert-XAMLtoWindow
{
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]
    $XAML,

    [string[]]
    $NamedElement=$null,

    [switch]
    $PassThru
  )

  Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

  $reader = [XML.XMLReader]::Create([IO.StringReader]$XAML)
  $result = [Windows.Markup.XAMLReader]::Load($reader)
  foreach($Name in $NamedElement)
  {
    $result | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name $Name -Value $result.FindName($Name) -Force
  }

  if ($PassThru)
  {
    $result
  }
  else
  {
    $null = $window.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync{
      $result = $window.ShowDialog()
      Set-Variable -Name result -Value $result -Scope 1
    }.Wait()
    $result
  }
}

function Show-WPFWindow
{
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [Windows.Window]
    $Window
  )

  $result = $null
  $null = $window.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync{
    $result = $window.ShowDialog()
    Set-Variable -Name result -Value $result -Scope 1
  }.Wait()
  $result
}
#endregion Code Behind

#region Convert XAML to Window
$window = Convert-XAMLtoWindow -XAML $xaml -NamedElement 'ButCancel', 'ButOk', 'ref', 'TxtEmail', 'TxtName' -PassThru
#endregion

#region Define Event Handlers
# Right-Click XAML Text and choose WPF/Attach Events to
# add more handlers
$window.ButCancel.add_Click(
  {
    $window.DialogResult = $false  
  }
)


$window.ButOk.add_Click(
  {
    $window.DialogResult = $true
  }

)
#endregion Event Handlers

#region Manipulate Window Content
#$window.TxtName.Text = $env:username
$window.ref.Text = $ref
$window.TxtName.Text = $123
$window.TxtEmail.Text = $toEmail
$null = $window.TxtName.Focus()

#endregion

# Show Window
$result = Show-WPFWindow -Window $window
```

If i use ISE Steroids to add an event I get similar to this

```
$window.ButOk.add_KeyDown{
  # remove param() block if access to event information is not required
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][Object]$sender,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs]$e
  )

  # add event code here
}
```

Comment: Quicksearch for C# shows you need a PreviewKeyDown handler, here's an outdated example for PS: [link](http://itnotes.net/category/scripting/powershell-scripting/)

Comment: The escape key already works with your code because of `IsCancel="True"` in your XAML. Just add `IsDefault="True"`for "ButOk" in the XAML and your OK button will be selected when you will press enter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with key down events can be a bit tricky since these are depending on the current UIFocus, therefor your button does not act on any keydown event since it is not in the current focus scope when you´re just editing the Textboxes. Since you only plan on using this simple form, I would suggest adding an event handler to your window that handles this. So your code behind section should look something like this:

```
$window.add_KeyDown{
param
(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][Object]$sender,
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs]$e
)
if($e.Key == $Key.Return)
{
    $window.DialogResult = $true
}

if($e.Key -eq $Key.Escape)
{
    $window.DialogResult = $false
}    
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't get that code to work. It doesn't like the double `=` and when I remove them I get a InvalidOperation on the `if($e.Key == $Key.Return)` bit.

Comment: Please try 
     if($e.Key -eq $Key.Return)

Comment: Closer! No error anymore, but the keys don't do anything.

Comment: Got it - just this. `if($e.Key -eq 'Enter')` Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me yet but it helped me a lot so I'm answering here.

I made a simple form with https://poshgui.com/Editor adding the code in the answer and got the error message:

*System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Unable to find type [Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs]*.

My TextBox element has got the focus, so I created the event for it:

```
TextBoxSearchInput.Add_KeyDown{
        param ( 
            [Parameter(Mandatory)][Object]$sender,
            [Parameter(Mandatory)][System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs]$e
        )
        if($e.Key -eq $Key.Return){
            $FormOkButton.PerformClick()
        }
        if($e.Key -eq $Key.Escape){
            $Form.close()
        }
    }
```

There may be a better way than "PerformClick" but for now it works.

Comment: Doesn't work either because $Key.Return always gives back "True".

Comment: `if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape")` and `if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape")` is the working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread here is old but I was also sucessfull with this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms    
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Build Form
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Any Name"
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(700,150) #use any size
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen" # I prefer this
$Form.Topmost = $true 


$form.KeyPreview = $true #This is the important part
$form.Add_KeyDown{
    param ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][Object]$sender,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs]$e
    )
    if($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape"){
        $Form.close()
    }
}
```